# How do I display div inline + animated logo

Tags: image, css, animation, html

Im trying to make a logo animation, but I can't do it because the "gg" part is below the actual logo.

Like, our insignia is 1*GG, and when you hover over it, it turns into 1S***GG (the "hot" being the animation)

Instead, the "GG" is below the actual logo, so how can I fix this?

Also another thing, how do I activate the animation when you hover over the "GG" part of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `float:left` property

If not then just put the `GG` image in a `Div` then give both the `div's` `float:left` property and you are done.

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F6VEB/)

---

**Edit :**
I have done the hover animation on `GG` image using jQuery it is pretty simple

Explaining what i have done then i have just given a class to the `GG` image div and on hovering on that div i added and removed a class that increases the width of `logoshot` class

Here is the [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F6VEB/2/) that might explain/clear your doubts.

Comment: @PlusOne what scripting language are you using ?? Cause i dont think you can do the animation on hover of `GG` image by css..

Comment: Its just a simple css3/jquery/html5 design for a myBB theme. Thanks a bunch!